# Python Asyncua OPC UA server Client error, The specified secure channel is no longer valid.(BadSecureChannelIdInvalid)

Tags: python, python-asyncio, opc-ua

I am trying to create the OPCUA client using Python AsyncUA library. I am using the sample client program but facing  **The specified secure channel is no longer valid.(BadSecureChannelIdInvalid)** error in the console.

```
import asyncio
from asyncua import Client

async def read_opcua_node(endpoint_url, node_id):
    async with Client(url=endpoint_url) as client:
        # Connect to the server
        await client.connect()

        # Read the node value
        node = await client.get_node(node_id)
        value = await node.read_value()

        # Print the result
        print(f"Value of node {node_id}: {value}")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    endpoint_url = "opc.tcp://172.10.0.13:4840"
    node_id = "ns=2;i=0"

    # Run the script
    asyncio.run(read_opcua_node(endpoint_url, node_id))
```

----------- console error --------------------

```
Requested session timeout to be 3600000ms, got 60000ms instead
Received an error: ErrorMessage(Error=StatusCode(value=2149711872), Reason=None)
Received an error: ErrorMessage(Error=StatusCode(value=2149711872), Reason=None)
Got error status from server: The specified secure channel is no longer valid.(BadSecureChannelIdInvalid)
close_secure_channel was called but connection is closed
disconnect_socket was called but connection is closed
close_session was called but connection is closed
close_secure_channel was called but connection is closed
disconnect_socket was called but connection is closed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kavimuthurajas/PycharmProjects/Amber-OPCGateway/OPCUAClient.py", line 22, in <module>
    asyncio.run(read_opcua_node(endpoint_url, node_id))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/kavimuthurajas/PycharmProjects/Amber-OPCGateway/OPCUAClient.py", line 7, in read_opcua_node
    await client.connect()
  File "/Users/kavimuthurajas/PycharmProjects/Amber-OPCGateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asyncua/client/client.py", line 310, in connect
    await self.create_session()
  File "/Users/kavimuthurajas/PycharmProjects/Amber-OPCGateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asyncua/client/client.py", line 489, in create_session
    response = await self.uaclient.create_session(params)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/kavimuthurajas/PycharmProjects/Amber-OPCGateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asyncua/client/ua_client.py", line 335, in create_session
    data = await self.protocol.send_request(request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/kavimuthurajas/PycharmProjects/Amber-OPCGateway/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asyncua/client/ua_client.py", line 170, in send_request
    raise ConnectionError("Connection is closed") from None
ConnectionError: Connection is closed
```

Process finished with exit code 1.

Answer (score 0):

You try to connect multiple times remove the `client.connect` line. The `async with` alread does the connect.

```
   async with Client(url=endpoint_url) as client:
        # Connect to the server
        #### ----> remove await client.connect()
         # Read the node value
        node = await client.get_node(node_id)
        value = await node.read_value()

        # Print the result
        print(f"Value of node {node_id}: {value}")
```